# Can I have multiple query_sets for a view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a view that I allow `get`, `put` and `delete`.  I want to have a queryset for my `get` and a different one for my `put` and `delete` (2 different querysets).  I guess in my `get_queryset` method, I can check the request action but I just wanted to double check and see if this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this works, i've been using it to use different serializers in get_serializer_class(self), but you can try this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        return Model.objects.filter()
    elif self.action == 'retrieve':
        return Model.objects.filter()
```

these are the actions: list, retrieve, update, destroy, partial_update, create.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I said I'm currently thinking of doing but it didn't feel like the right way.  Was looking to see other solutions, if any exist.  But yes, this is the way you get different serializers for sure.

Comment: `self.action won't work for all views. `self.request.method` is more convenient. @alex

Comment: @Pittfall This is the best solution and the DRF way. Don't hesitate

Comment: @JPG can you elaborate what you mean by `self.action won't work for all views.`

Comment: if you are using **`APIView`** class, `self.action` won;t work